# Why does this Password Verification code not work with jquery form wizard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using a jquery form wizard for my form, it is a multiple page form, example below:
**http://thecodemine.org/examples/example_1_straight.html**

The form is using a jquery validation plugin, & in the *jquery.validation.js* , there is no validation rule for password or to check retype password.

I tried many other simple verification form codes, but they don't work with form wizard, it may be because as this is the multiple page form, & it doesn't pass the information when I click on **next button**

If I use mootools to verify then jquery form wizard stop doing work.

I am trying to use the simple code mentioned after a small customization, but it also doesn't work on the form either, however it works on other simple forms.

**Kindly guide me on how can I use this script in my page, which is exactly similar with the example on the above mentioned link.**

**First I call pass the values to form wizard to create the animated form, code mentioned below**

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#SignupForm").formwizard({ 
                formPluginEnabled: true,
                validationEnabled: true,
                focusFirstInput : true,
                formOptions :{
                    success: function(data){$("#status").fadeTo(500,1,function(){ $(this).html("You are now registered!").fadeTo(5000, 0); })},
                    beforeSubmit: function(data){$("#data").html("data sent to the server: " + $.param(data));},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    resetForm: true
                }   
             }
            );
    });
</script>
```

**Below is the verification code which I am trying to use in the form, but it doesn't work**

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

var pass1 = $('#password'),
    pass2 = $('#passwordConfirm'),
    email = $('#email'),
    form = $('#SignupForm'),
    strength = $('#strength'),
    arrow = $('#form-div .arrow');

// Empty the fields on load
$('#main .row input').val('');

// Handle form submissions
form.on('submit',function(e){

    // Is everything entered correctly?
    if($('#main .row.success').length == $('#main .row').length){

        // Yes!
        alert("Thank you for trying out this demo!");
        e.preventDefault(); // Remove this to allow actual submission

    }
    else{

        // No. Prevent form submission
        e.preventDefault();

    }
});

// Validate the email field
email.on('blur',function(){

    // Very simple validation
    if (!/^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/.test(email.val())){
        email.parent().addClass('error').removeClass('success');
    }
    else{
        email.parent().removeClass('error').addClass('success');
    }

});

// Use the complexify plugin on the first password field
pass1.complexify({minimumChars:7, strengthScaleFactor:0.4}, function(valid, complexity){

    if(valid){
        pass2.removeAttr('disabled');

        pass1.parent()
                .removeClass('error')
                .addClass('success');
    }
    else{
        pass2.attr('disabled','true');

        pass1.parent()
                .removeClass('success')
                .addClass('error');
    }



    var calculated = (complexity/100)*268-30;
    if(calculated <50){
    $('#strength').text('Very Weak');

    strength.removeClass('GreenJoy').addClass('RedWarn');

    }

    if(calculated >50 && calculated < 100){
    $('#strength').text('Weak');

    strength.removeClass('GreenJoy').addClass('RedWarn');

    }

    if(calculated >100 && calculated < 150){
    $('#strength').text('Normal');

    strength.removeClass('RedWarn').addClass('GreenJoy');

    }

    if(calculated >170 && calculated < 200){
    $('#strength').text('Good');

    strength.removeClass('RedWarn').addClass('GreenJoy');
    }

    if(calculated >235){
    $('#strength').text('Perfect!');

    strength.removeClass('RedWarn').addClass('GreenJoy');
    }


});

// Validate the second password field
pass2.on('keydown input',function(){

    // Make sure its value equals the first's
    if(pass2.val() == pass1.val()){

        pass2.parent()
                .removeClass('error')
                .addClass('success');
    }
    else{
        pass2.parent()
                .removeClass('success')
                .addClass('error');
    } 
});

 });

</script>
```

Comment: Is there any idea how to implement it with the form wizard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it:)

there is a validation rule equalTo in **jquery.validate.js**

i do this to get password velidation

**HTML**

```
   <label for="password">Password</label>
<label for="password" id="strength" style="font-weight:normal"></label>
<input class="ui-wizard-content ui-helper-reset ui-state-default" disabled="disabled" name="password" id="password" type="password">

<label for="passwordConfirm">Retype password</label>

<input class="ui-wizard-content ui-helper-reset ui-state-default equalTo required" disabled="disabled" name="passwordConfirm" id="passwordConfirm" type="password">
```

**JavaScript**

```
  <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#SignupForm").validate({
 rules: {
password: "required",
passwordConfirm: {
  equalTo: "#password"
}
}
});
 });
 </script>
```